# Tomcat Parallel Deployment, automatically undeploy old applications

Tags: tomcat, deployment, continuous-integration

I've been using Tomcat 8's Parallel Deployment as part of a zero-downtime continuous deployment setup for a while now.

When the test gauntlet has been run, the CI server automatically renames the .war file to application##{version-number}.war and copies the war to the /webapp folder. application##333 will coexist nicely with application##332.

The only problem that I'm encountering is that I have to manually undeploy the older applications once all traffic (new sessions) have automatically transitioned to the new one.

Does Tomcat have some built-in mechanism for saying "hey, when this service gets down to zero sessions, it should be removed"? Maybe some sort of "the last session has just expired" event that I can tap into.

If anyone else has automated this kind of application undeploy, I would love to hear about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can configure Tomcat to remove the old applications. You need to add the `undeployOldVersions` attribute to the `Host` element and set it to `true`. You'll need to modify your host in server.xml to something like the following:

```
<Host undeployOldVersions="true" ...>
   ...
</Host>
```

See the [Host documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) for details. In particular, this only works when automatic deployment is enabled.

Comment: Under what version of Tomcat are  you running? I have Tomcat 8.5.6 and this does not work. I have enabled FarmWarDeployer, and new releases are automatically deployed. However, after enabled undeployOldVersions on the Host tag, the older war files (and deployments) are not deleted.

Comment: Any progress on this with Tomcat 8?

Comment: The feature is implemented for Tomcat 8. If you are seeing issues when using FarmWarDeployer then open a bug, with steps to reproduce, so it gets looked at.